# Receive module not found error after i pip mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, pip, pycharm, spyder

i run this command `pip3 install mysql-connector` in Command Prompt and its show this:
`C:\Users\pc>pip3 install mysql-connector Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\prog rams\python\python38\lib\site-packages (2.2.9)`.
but i still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'` when i `import mysql.connector` in spyder and pycahrm.

Comment: Are Spyder and Pycharm both using that Python installation, or could you have another one on your machine? How did you install Spyder?

Comment: i found two python,first one is in the spyder folder and when i import 'mysql.connector' it show not found error,the other one is in my C DRIVE and it can import 'mysql.connector'.

Comment: Should i delete the first one?

Comment: No - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spyder go to **Tools** > **Preferences** > **Python interpreter**, select  **Use the following Python interpreter:** and choose the Python .exe from your other installation.

There is probably a similar setting in Pycharm’s preferences.

Comment: in spyder i keep get `ModuleNotFoundError`.but pycharm raise this error `mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported`.

Comment: i use this command `pip install mysql-connector-python`. and i get another error:`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'yourusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`